# Create face from edges creates wrong face

Tags: modeling, faces, edges

I am trying to create a simple arrow face. When I select all edges and press <kbd>F</kbd>, I get an extra undesired face.

[image]

[[image]

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>F</kbd> should work...

[image]

Have you checked for double vertices left over from a 'cancelled' extrusion? A right-click doesn't cancel the generation of new geometry by an extrusion / inset; it only cancels the move. Right-click drops the new geometry in place. Select all, and <kbd>M</kbd> > Merge > By Distance, to be sure.